# В npm при установке пакета ошибки выходят. В чем причина?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/uswer/Documents/test/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/uswer/Documents/test/package.json'
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README data
npm WARN test No license field.
```

Comment: Судя по сему,  жалуется на отсутствие файла `package.json` который надо создать командой `npm init`

Comment: Спасибо. Все так.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста....